# How can I use segmented control to swap Map type?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want from someone to help me to find a solution how can i add or connect segmentation maptype (Standard, Satellite, Hybrid) to my Master view controller.

Comment: @Jalaldin - for us to be able to help you, we need to know what you have tried to do so far and where you are getting stuck.  Your question is really vague at the moment and is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil]];
      [segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
      [segControl setFrame:CGRectMake(50,20,200,44)];//set frame which you want
      [self.view addSubview:segControl];
}

- (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {
    switch (aSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
                break;
            case 1:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
                break;
            case 2:
                map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: ![i want to connect segcontrol to another view controller][1]


![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mMHY2.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YLiXS.png

Comment: you could display your view controller as a modal view controller with page curl transition...